# How to convert bitmap to ASCII

Tags: python, bitmap, ascii, maze

I have a maze bitmap with (255, 255, 255) for the walls and (0, 0, 0) for the clear space i want to convert it into "#" for walls and " " for clear space in python with the format -

```
            Start
maze = ["#", " ", "#", "#", "#"],
       ["#", " ", " ", "#", "#"],
       ["#", "#", " ", "#", "#"],
       ["#", "#", " ", " ", "#"],
       ["#", "#", "#", " ", "#"],
                      Finish
```

Is there a faster way to do this than manually typing it because it is a very large maze? (I am a beginner and just made a maze solving algorithm and want to see the way it solves a large maze so i can improve on it)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885713) and its answers will give you insight into converting a bitmap to an array.

Comment: Yes, you can do that with python. With PIL, for example you can read images: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/ . Then you can run over the image coordinates in a for loop and write you own matirx....

Comment: @Maecky Thank you i have a lot of trouble with getting down voted because i ask an almost duplicate question because i cant understand the other posts :(

Comment: @J.Clarke I notice that generally people write questions in a way that is most understandable to them and not to others - so I think that's the reason for the large amount of duplicates on this site and not the lack of research :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

```
def processMaze (mazeArray):
    maze = []
    for mazeRow in mazeArray:
        tempMazeRow = []
        for mazeColumn in mazeRow:
            if mazeColumn == (255, 255, 255):
                tempMazeRow.append('#')
            elif mazeColumn == (0, 0, 0):
                tempMazeRow.append(" ")
        maze.append(tempMazeRow)
    return maze
```