# How to load my model to identified a picture's class

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to identified a picture's class (I mean which class it belong to) , using my own model. Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import Alex
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import urllib2


slim = tf.contrib.slim
checkpoints_dir = '/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/AlexNet/test/'
image_size = 56

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    filename = "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/test_abc/10.bmp"
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    processed_image=tf.image.resize_images(image, [56,56], method=0)
    processed_images = tf.expand_dims(processed_image, 0)
    logits = Alex.inference(processed_images, None)
    probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoints_dir)
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            ckpt_name = os.path.basename(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
            save_path = "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/AlexNet/test/model.ckpt"
            saver.restore(sess, os.path.join(checkpoints_dir, ckpt_name))

            np_image, network_input, probabilities = sess.run([image,
                                                               processed_image,
                                                               probabilities])

            probabilities = probabilities[0, 0:]
            sorted_inds = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(-probabilities),
                                                key=lambda x: x[1])]
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.imshow(np_image.astype(np.uint8))
    plt.suptitle("Downloaded image", fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
    plt.axis('off')
```

It seems that something is wrong in load my model. Dose somebody know how to realize it? I am eager to know it. Thank you very much

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: The error is "name 'np_image' is not defined" , but I don't know whether my cord is right. And don't how to return the class of the picture.Can you help me?

Comment: The problem might be that your image is in bitmap format. Look [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/428) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604530/how-to-read-bmp-files-in-tensorflow) for more information

Comment: Thank you for your help . But I still don't understand how to read a bmp image . And in my code , I think this step is not run : 'np_image, network_input, probabilities = sess.run([image,processed_image, probabilities])' . Maybe the method that load model is wrong . But I just don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you are trying to read a bpm image using the jpg method. The way tensorflow works the error comes up when the load-image node of the graph is evaluated, in your case when you call `sess.run([image, processed_image, probabilities])`. To load the bitmap in a numpy array look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885713/how-to-get-an-array-from-rgb-values-of-a-bitmap-image). Then you can turn it into a tf variable.

Comment: The error "name 'np_image' is not defined" means that no value was ever assigned to a variable called `np_image`. Looking at your code, it is only assigned in the true branch of the `if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:` statement, so this suggests that either `ckpt` is `None` or `ckpt.model_checkpoint_path` is `None`.

Comment: Thank you very much . But I don't understand ,  I just want to use my model to identify a picture's class . But I am not good in tensorflow , so I don't know how to fix my code . Can you tell me how to fix it ?